# Shared memory in process address space?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, ipc, shared-memory

I know from my reading of OS concepts book that process in memory consists from: text section, data section, stack and heap.

But I am asking about when a process asks Kernel to create a shared memory segment when this section is created? in heap?

---

Another question Kernel knows information about every process in the system in PCB format and save this PCB in process-table.

The question is: is the process-table doubly-linked list?

Comment: Yes it is doubly linked list (struct list_head tasks;) But CFS scheduler uses RB-tree to maintain runqueue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose that your question is about a process memory layout.
If so, Linux and Solaris processes have the following sections:

```
Text
Data
BSS
Heap
MMS (memory mapping segment)
Stack
```

The memory array between the Heap and Stack, so called **Memory Mapping Segment**, is responsible for the shared memory mapping. And not only. Shared libraries, opened files are also mapped into that section of memory.

You may examine process memory layout on Linux by **pmap**  command or reading the process maps file **/proc//maps**.
Here is a fragment of a DB2 process memory layout examined on a Linux machine by the pmap utility (look at the stack and shmid, shared memory ID, entries):

```
0000000000400000     52K r-x--  /opt/ibm/db2/bin/db2vend
000000000060d000      4K rwx--  /opt/ibm/db2/bin/db2vend
000000000c33e000    132K rwx--    [ anon ]
0000000200000000  35520K rwxs-    [ shmid=0x57a58007 ]
000000323f200000    112K r-x--  /lib64/ld-2.5.so
and more more more shared libraries
00002b55bb45b000      4K r-x--  /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
00002b55bb45c000      4K rwx--  /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
00002b55bb45d000  39252K rwxs-    [ shmid=0x57a50006 ]
00002b55bdab2000   1152K rwx--    [ anon ]
00007ffffaf35000     84K rwx--    [ stack ]
ffffffffff600000   8192K -----    [ anon ]
```